# Calling a table with AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

nformation about a bitcoin block can be obtained via [https://explorer.api.bitcoin.com/bch/v1/block/[BLOCK-HASH]](https://explorer.api.bitcoin.com/bch/v1/block/%5BBLOCK-HASH%5D)

For example,
https://explorer.api.bitcoin.com/bch/v1/block/00000000000000000272f89a3e1883efc2ab81a6167ce66030f11b980d6db501

https://explorer.api.bitcoin.com/bch/v1/block/000000000000000001e046cc5d9023e7783d0526c8030d5f4d26beafa330bca3

https://explorer.api.bitcoin.com/bch/v1/block/0000000000000000022a8d56ceca32156dc906b4adc93565358ac4c4349e59e2

https://explorer.api.bitcoin.com/bch/v1/block/00000000000000000166f6ddb85c4984213a9f7a0d40bfa7af5ca48dface7334

Your task is to create a webpage, and on the web page, display a text field with the instruction "Enter a bitcoin block hash: ".

On the webpage, display a button "Get Bitcoin Block Information".

Whenever the user enters a bitcoin block hash and clicks the button, make the appropriate AJAX call to retrieve the bitcoin block JSON. On the website, dynamically create a table to display the bitcoin block information:

the table has 6 rows and 2 columns

the 1st row displays hash information

the 2nd row displays size information

the 3rd row displays height information

the 4th-row displays version information

the 5th row displays Merkle root information

the 6th-row displays tx information

The tax information must be displayed in an unordered list.
If the user enters an invalid bitcoin block hash then the webpage should display an error message "Invalid bitcoin block hash" in red color.

Note that: you must use the method in our lecture to make the AJAX call. Other ajax library is not allowed and you will not get the mark for it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Exercise 3</title>
   
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function newAjaxQuery(){
            
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                readyStateChangeHandler(xmlhttp);
            }

            var hashInput = document.getElementById("bitcoin");
            var hash = hashInput.value;
            var query1 = "https://explorer.api.bitcoin.com/bch/v1/block/00000000000000000272f89a3e1883efc2ab81a6167ce66030f11b980d6db501";
            xmlhttp.open("GET", query1, true);
            xmlhttp.send();

        }

        function readyStateChangeHandler(xmlhttp) {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
                if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
                    handleStatusSuccess(xmlhttp);
                } else {
                    handleStatusFailure(xmlhttp);
                }
            }
        }

        function handleStatusSuccess(xmlhttp){
            
            var jsonText = xmlhttp.responseText;
            var obj = JSON.parse(jsonText);
            display(obj);
            }


        function handleStatusFailure(xmlhttp){
            
            alert("AJAX request has failed");
            alert("readyState = " + xmlhttp.readyState);
            alert("status = " + xmlhttp.status);

            var displayDiv = document.getElementById("display");
            var html ="";

            html += "<span style='color:red> Invalid bitcoin block hash </span>'"

            displayDiv.innerHTML = html;
            }


        function display(){

            var displayDiv = document.getElementById("display");
            displayDiv.innerHTML = html;

            var html ="";

            html += "<table border = '1 '>";
            html += "<tr><th>Hash information</th><td>" + jsonObject.hash + "</td></tr>";
            html += "<tr><th>Size</th><td>" +jsonObject.size + "</td></tr>";
            html += "<tr><th>Height</th><td>" +jsonObject.height + "</td></tr>";
            html += "<tr><th>Version</th><td>" +jsonObject.ver + "</td></tr>";
            html += "<tr><th>merkleroot</th><td>" +jsonObject.mrk1_root + "</td></tr>";
            html += "<tr><th>tx</th><td><ul>";
                for (var i =0; i < jsonObject.tx.length; i++){
                    var successfultx = jsonObject.tx[i];
                html += "<li>" + successfultx.hash + "</li>";
            }

            html += "</ul></td>";
            html += "</table>";
        }
            
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <label for="bitcoin">Enter a bitcoin block hash: </label><br>
            <input type="text" id="bitcoin" name="bitcoin"><br>

            <button type="button" onClick="newAjaxQuery()">Get Bitcoin Block Information</button>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the question? Have you debugged the code you've written? At what point does it break? Does it break? We can't help if we don't know what the question is.  You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Where's the documentation page that mentions the use of `"https://explorer.api.bitcoin.com/bch/v1/block/[BLOCK_HASH]" + hash;` ?
From the page here: `https://explorer.api.bitcoin.com/docs/bch/v1/#/block/blockSummary`, I'd expect the request to be `https://explorer.api.bitcoin.com/bch/v2/blockSummary/0000000000000000008e8d83cba6d45a9314bc2ef4538d4e0577c6bed8593536`, where everything after the last slash is the actual hash of the transaction you're interested in.. The key point being the  text `[hash]` is replaced with the actual hash, rather than having the hash _appended_ at the end. ;)

Comment: I have updated the question specifications to exactly what the task is asking us to complete